# Valid Postgres query alway return undefined

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, pgadmin

I am using sails to build an API, one of my function needs to get columns from my PGSQL database. My SQL request is working when I test it in PGadmin, it looks like this :

```
SELECT "user".id, "user".picture, "user".first_name, "trophe".trophe FROM "user" INNER JOIN "trophe" ON "trophe".user  = "user".id WHERE "trophe".foot = 1
```

When I transcript this request in my sails API, it looks like this :

```
  getHommeAndChevre: function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.param("id"));
    Trophe.query("SELECT 'user'.id, 'user'.picture, 'user'.first_name, 'trophe'.trophe FROM 'user' INNER JOIN 'trophe' ON 'trophe'.user = 'user'.id WHERE 'trophe'.foot ="+req.param('id'), function(err,trophes){
      if(!trophes) {return res.status(400).end();}
      if(trophes){
        _each(trophes, function(trophe){
          if (trophe.trophe == 0) {var chevre = trophe};
          if (trophe.trophe == 1) { var homme = trophe};
        })
       return res.status(200).json({chevre: chevre, homme: homme})
      }
    });
  }
```

However whatever I do the Trophe.query always returned `undefined`. What could be wrong here ?

Comment: Your problem is the single quotes on that fields, either change it to double quotes or remove then all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes for identifiers

```
Trophe.query('SELECT "user".id, "user".picture, "user".first_name, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return is outside the callback , so you return the value before the end of the query.

```
_each(trophes, function(trophe, index){
      if (trophe.trophe == 0) {var chevre = trophe};
      if (trophe.trophe == 1) { var homme = trophe};
      if (index == trophes.length - 1) //End of the loop
          return res.status(200).json({chevre: chevre, homme: homme});
})
```